# Error: Cannot get orders: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express

I'm trying to build an API with express and pg. Whenever I try to access an endpoint that is related to a query to the database I get the error above.

My handler function is as follows:

```
import { Request, Response, Router, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Orders } from '../models/order';

const orders = new Orders;

const index = async (_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
try {
    const ordersList = await orders.index();
    res.json(ordersList);
} catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}

const ordersRoute = Router();

ordersRoute.get('/', index);
```

This handler refers to the following model:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

client = new Pool({
 host: POSTGRES_HOST,
 database: POSTGRES_DB,
 user: POSTGRES_USER,
 password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
 port: parseInt(POSTGRES_PORT as string, 10)

export class Orders {
 async index(): Promise<Order[]> {
  try {
   const conn = await client.connect();
   const sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders';
   const result = await conn.query(sql);
   conn.release();
   return result.rows;
  } catch (err) {
   throw new Error(`Cannot get orders: ${err}`);
   }
 }
}
```

anytime I try to access the endpoint I get

> Error: Cannot get orders: TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'connect')

in the console.
any idea how to fix ?

Comment: Do you pass the `client` object in any way to the Orders?

Comment: @MichałSadowski No. I'm only using it as a Pool from the pg dependancy as edited in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So how things work in your case.

All modules are read by nodejs starting from your index one by one from top to bottom.
In your script, you declare `client` and then export a `class`. In that case, your `client` is setup, then you export a class, and that file is completed, meaning that the only thing that remains is the `exported` thing. So when you try to use the `exported` class, you'll not have the same context as in your module.

You need to export the `client` too and import it where you need that class or to include `client` definition inside the class

Comment: Well I got it fixed, turns out my function's logic for exporting the client variable was wrong and I had to rewrite it. Thanks.